# Angular 5 button not behaving properly

Tags: angular, typescript

I did this tutorial that I found on YouTube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GEdxydnpNFs) and I can't get the Edit button to populate the fields on the left. Here's the relevant snippets of code:

employee-list.component.html

```
    <h6 class="text-center">Employee Register</h6><br>
    <table class="table table-sm table-hover">
    <tr *ngFor="let employee of employeeList">
        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
        <td>{{employee.position}}</td>
        <td>
            <a class="btn" (click)="onEdit(employee)">
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="btn" (click)="onDelete(employee.$key)">
                <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

employee-list.component.ts

```
    onEdit(emp : Employee){
        this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = Object.assign({}, emp);
  }
```

employee.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase, AngularFireList } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { Employee } from './employee.model';

@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

    employeeList : AngularFireList<any>;
    selectedEmployee : Employee = new Employee();

  constructor(private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }
    getData(){
        this.employeeList = this.firebase.list('employees');
        return this.employeeList;
    }

    insertEmployee(employee : Employee){
        this.employeeList.push({
            name: employee.name,
            position: employee.position,
            office: employee.office,
            salary: employee.salary
        });
    }

    updateEmployee(employee : Employee){
        this.employeeList.update(employee.$key, 
            {
            name: employee.name,
            position: employee.position,
            office: employee.office,
            salary: employee.salary
        });
    }

    deleteEmployee($key : string){
        this.employeeList.remove($key);
    }
}
```

I've tried debugging and it seems that the onEdit() method is being called but it's not populating the fields. Any help here would be appreciated.

employee.component.html

```
    <form #employeeForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(employeeForm)">
    <input type="hidden" name="$key" #$key="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.$key">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Position</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="position" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.position" placeholder="Position">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Office</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="office" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.office" placeholder="Office">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Salary</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <div class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
            </div>
        <input class="form-control" name="salary" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.salary" placeholder="Salary">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" [disabled]="!employeeForm.valid">
            <i class="fa fa-floppy-o"></i>
            Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="resetForm(employeeForm)">
            <i class="fa fa-repeat"></i>
            Reset</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

employee.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';
import { EmployeeService } from '../shared/employee.service';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee',
  templateUrl: './employee.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private employeeService : EmployeeService, private tostr : ToastrService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
  }

  onSubmit(employeeForm : NgForm){
    if(employeeForm.value.$key == null)
        this.employeeService.insertEmployee(employeeForm.value);
    else
                this.employeeService.updateEmployee(employeeForm.value);

    this.resetForm(employeeForm);
    this.tostr.success('Submitted Successfully', 'Employee Register');
  }

  resetForm(employeeForm? : NgForm){
    if(employeeForm != null)
        employeeForm.reset();
    this.employeeService.selectedEmployee = {
        $key : null,
        name : '',
        position : '',
        office : '',
        salary : 0
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `employee.component.html` file contains the problem. You're populating your form model with lines like `[(ngModel)]="employeeService.name"`. Your `employeeService` service does not have a `name` property or method though, so `employeeService.name` will return `undefined`. I'm assuming you want to call `employeeService.selectedEmployee.name` because you want to populate the form with the selected employee's `name`.

So the answer might look something like:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="name" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.name" placeholder="Full Name" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Position</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="position" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.position" placeholder="Position">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Office</label>
  <input class="form-control" name="office" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.office" placeholder="Office">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Salary</label>
  <div class="input-group">
    <div class="input-group-addon">
      <i class="fa fa-dollar"></i>
    </div>
    <input class="form-control" name="salary" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="employeeService.selectedEmployee.salary" placeholder="Salary">
  </div>
</div>
```

### Update

I notice you have `employeeService` set as `private` in `employee.component.ts` (i.e. `constructor(private employeeService, ...` ). I think that should generate an error if/when you try and access the `employeeService` directly in the component's template (`employee.component.html`). To start with, I'd just switch that `private` keyword to `public` and make sure things work. If you know the difference between `private` and `public`, you can go about cleaning it up if the problem is solved. If you don't know the difference between the two, probably just leave it as `public` (which is sloppy, but whatever).

Comment: Your edit in employee.component.html was right--changing employeeService.selectedEmployee.name/position/office/salary. Bonehead mistake on my part. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Update your EmployeeService like below. Add some getter and setter methods.

```
@Injectable()
export class EmployeeService {

    employeeList : AngularFireList<any>;
    _selectedEmployee : Employee = new Employee();

    constructor(private firebase : AngularFireDatabase) { }

    //Adding getter and setter below

    get selectedEmployee():Employee{
        return this._selectedEmployee ;
    }

    set selectedEmployee(emp:Employee) {
        this._selectedEmployee = emp;
    }

......
    ......
.....
}
```

My guess is your onEdit is not able to set or update your selected employee. So using the getter/setter above should be the right way.

Comment: I noticed your code is setting the selectedEmployee. However, i don't see the left side implementation where you supposedly used it. Can you share that ?

Comment: Just added the left side implementation.

Comment: Are `employee.component.ts` and `employee-list.component.ts` in the same module ? You are not initializing EmployeeService in `employee-list.component.ts` are you ? You should add your service Declaration app.module only .

Comment: I have a folder called employees that has folders in it (component folders) for employee and employee-list.

Comment: I am talking about module. Can you share your module file above ? I want to see how you declare your service . It will not work if they are not in a seperate module.